# Icono de aplicación android no se cambia Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

Intento agregar el icono a mi aplicación, inserto el icono en formato png en todas las carpetas mipmap, selecciono en propiedades del proyecto Android el icono de la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y selecciono la ruta del icono en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application android:label="SequoSentry" android:icon="@mipmap/seq"></application>
```

Pero en las pruebas con el emulador no me figura el icono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si genero un .apk para probarlo e instalarlo en mi móvil el icono de la aplicación me figura en los mensajes de advertencia de instalar app de fuentes desconocidas, pero luego no me figura en el menú de aplicaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver el nombre de la aplicación tampoco se cambia al seleccionado en el AndroidManifest ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o que paso me olvido?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO:

Había olvidado modificar el directorio del icono y el label en el archivo MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "SequoSentry", Icon = "@mipmap/seq", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```